# How to paste range from different workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

My code:

```vb
With wbImport.Worksheets("Data")
    LastCol = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    LastRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    .Range("A1", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Copy ' ‹-- Copy without Select
End With
    
wsData.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I am trying to paste Data fom wbImport into my current workbook wsData.

Almost every time I get

> Error 1004 Paste Special method of Range class failed.

Comment: which line yealds the error? Where/how is `wsData` defined?

Comment: Use value transfer instead: `wsData.Range("A1").Resize(LastRow, LastCol).Value = .Range("A1", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Value` (move the `End With` to the end).

Comment: @BigBen, I was writing it in the meanwhile. Though in a slightly different "flavour"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go like follows:

```
Dim wsData As Worksheet
set wsData = ... ' <-- set your target sheet

With wbImport.Worksheets("Data")
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        wsData.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

EDIT:

should you be interested in *filtered* rows only, then you have to go back to `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` methods

```
wbImport.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsData.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```